# Retrieve Unique Column From LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, cordova, local, data-visualization

I want to retrieve unique column data from the local storage, but i dont know how to do it. I have stored whole data from server in local storage.

[Retrived data img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gepv.png)

```
    $("#btnlogin").click(function(){

        window.e = $("#mob").val();
        window.p = $("#key").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "URL",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { type:'login', phone: e, name: p },
            ContentType: "application/json",
            success: function(response)
            {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    window.dataToStore = JSON.stringify(response);
                    window.localStorage.setItem('someData', dataToStore);



            },
            error: function(err)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })
    });

    $("#x").click(function()
    {
        var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someData'));

        alert(""+localData);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the given data and store each value in a single row
Then you will be able to access to each value with the data key.

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function(){
        window.e = $("#mob").val();
        window.p = $("#key").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "URL",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { type:'login', phone: e, name: p },
            ContentType: "application/json",
            success: function(response)
            {
              var data = JSON.parse(response);
              $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                window.localStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(val));
              });
            },
            error: function(err)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })
    });

    $("#x").click(function()
    {
      var localData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var row = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
        localData.push(row);
      }
      console.log(localData);
    });
```

Comment: but for example if i have a column names "id" have value "5"...so the value of id is already define in the DB ..why i will define id in the local storage manuallly

Comment: @SawanKhandelwal I don't understand what you mean, are you talking of the retrieved data or stored data ?, by DB are you talking about your server or localstorage ??

Comment: I mean to say that i have an database on the server from where i am retrieving data and want that data to store in local storage..

Comment: after that i want to print data of particular column in alert box.

Comment: What is the purpose  of saving the data in localstorage? if you want to use the data from your server, you can set the data in a variable

Comment: if user is offline ..still he can use that data.

Comment: how does the data retrieved from your server looks like?

Comment: link pasted above..please check

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look if it makes sense to you

Comment: Just to make it legible! You can remove   that string

Comment: leave it...btw can you tell me how can i store server data in sqlite DB in phonegap application as per the current scenario

Comment: You could take a look to pouchDB database in your browser